# Golang imap.DialTLS Config example

Tags: ssl, go, imap

I used to be able to connect to port `143` of a mail server like this:

```
c, err := imap.Dial(mailServer)
```

The code above connects to port 143 of the `mailServer`. Now I have a new mail server only accepts port `993`. Looking at the Golang `imap` source code, the function `DialTLS` will connect to port `993`. The signature of `DialTLS` looks like this:

```
func DialTLS(addr string, config *tls.Config) (c *Client, err error)
```

Now I don't know how to construct the `*tls.Config`. I Googled around, but didn't not find anything really useful. Can someone show me some example how to construct the `*tls.Config`?

I tried to pass in `nil` as the second parameter, it compiles, and I didn't get any runtime error. But it seems no new mails were fetched, even I believe there should be.

My fetch mail code looks like this:

```
// testimap
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go-imap/go1/imap"
    "fmt"
    "net/mail"
    "time"
)

type Mail struct {
    Subject string
    Body    string
    From    string
    Uid     uint32
}

func FetchMail(lastUid uint32) []*Mail {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()
    //
    // Note: most of error handling code is omitted for brevity
    //
    var (
        c   *imap.Client
        cmd *imap.Command
        rsp *imap.Response
    )

    // Connect to the server
    c, err := imap.DialTLS(mailServer, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Remember to log out and close the connection when finished
    defer c.Logout(30 * time.Second)

    // Print server greeting (first response in the unilateral server data queue)
    //fmt.Println("Server says hello:", c.Data[0].Info)
    c.Data = nil

    // Enable encryption, if supported by the server
    if c.Caps["STARTTLS"] {
        c.StartTLS(nil)
    }

    // Authenticate
    if c.State() == imap.Login {
        c.Login(mailSupportUser, mailSupportPw)
    }

    //// List all top-level mailboxes, wait for the command to finish
    cmd, err = imap.Wait(c.List("", "%"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // Print mailbox information
    //fmt.Println("\nTop-level mailboxes:")
    //for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
    //  fmt.Println("|--", rsp.MailboxInfo())
    //}

    // Check for new unilateral server data responses
    //for _, rsp = range c.Data {
    //  fmt.Println("Server data:", rsp)
    //}
    c.Data = nil

    // Open a mailbox (synchronous command - no need for imap.Wait)
    c.Select("INBOX", true)
    //fmt.Print("\nMailbox status:\n", c.Mailbox)

    // Fetch the headers of the 10 most recent messages
    set, err := imap.NewSeqSet(fmt.Sprint(lastUid, ":*"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    //if c.Mailbox.Messages >= 10 {
    //  set.AddRange(c.Mailbox.Messages-9, c.Mailbox.Messages)
    //} else {
    //  set.Add("1:*")
    //}
    cmd, err = c.UIDFetch(set, "RFC822.HEADER", "RFC822.TEXT")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // Process responses while the command is running
    //fmt.Println("\nMost recent messages:")
    mails := make([]*Mail, 0, 10)
    for cmd.InProgress() {
        // Wait for the next response (no timeout)
        c.Recv(-1)

        // Process command data
        for _, rsp = range cmd.Data {
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            header := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.HEADER"])
            uid := imap.AsNumber((rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["UID"]))
            body := imap.AsBytes(rsp.MessageInfo().Attrs["RFC822.TEXT"])
            if msg, err := mail.ReadMessage(bytes.NewReader(header)); msg != nil {
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
                mail := &Mail{
                    Subject: msg.Header.Get("Subject"),
                    From:    msg.Header.Get("FROM"),
                    Body:    string(body),
                    Uid:     uid,
                }
                if mail.Uid < lastUid {
                    continue
                }
                mails = append(mails, mail)
            }
        }
        cmd.Data = nil
        c.Data = nil
    }

    // Check command completion status
    if rsp, err := cmd.Result(imap.OK); err != nil {
        if err == imap.ErrAborted {
            fmt.Println("Fetch command aborted")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Fetch error:", rsp.Info)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(mails)
    return mails
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First off, you should be using the [project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/mxk/go-imap) as the Google Code project stated development was moving to GitHub due to Google Code shutting down. It's a few commits ahead of the Google Code repo too, so you won't be getting any updates if you don't migrate to the GitHub repo.

Secondly, looking at the [package's demo](https://github.com/mxk/go-imap/blob/master/imap-demo/demo1.go#L107), passing `nil` to `DialTLS` as the TLS client seems to be the proper way to connect with a default TLS client.

From the information you've given, it seems like it may be an issue with your server accepting connections over that port. I would look into if the port is open to the client you're trying to connect from or if your IMAP server is even accepting TLS connections.

If you're absolutely sure it's not a server issue after further debugging, I would file an issue on the [project's GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/mxk/go-imap/issues) to get help from people who are more familiar with the package, seeing that it's a third party package.

Comment: Thanks you @AustinDizzy. I will change to Github version and try again. Now the server is serving a lot of clients and I'm pretty sure the port 993 is working properly. My previous server had 143 open, so I used  `imap.Dial`, and it fetched mails correctly. Now the only change is replacing `imap.Dial` with `imap.DialTLS`. It compiles, and runtime has no error. But no mail is fetched. I always get an empty array of mails from the code. I will try more and come back here to update what I find.